# Firebase admin sdk not syncing with the gradle

Tags: android, firebase, build, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have incorporated some libraries into my android app. I have connected it with Firebase cloud server. Now, I want to create tokens for User authentication. Firebase asks to add Firebase Admin Sdk to the gradle File. However, it shows error on building the gradle.
The sdk I am adding is   compile `'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'`

Following is the error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in
>   project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.0) and test app (2.0.1)
>   differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for
>   details.

My original code is :

```
apply plugin: com.android.application

android {

compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.delluser.oshoguide"

    minSdkVersion 17

    targetSdkVersion 25

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner

 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),

 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions
        {

            exclude 'META-INF/notice'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firebase-admin doesn't belong in an Android app.  It's for server side applications.  If you attempt to add it to an Android app, it will definitely collide with the other Firebase libraries.

If you want to mint custom auth tokens, you have to do that on a server.  Please note the title of the Firebase Admin SDK docs: [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Comment: so how do i carry out sign in , sign out for my android app directly connected to firebase