# Google Cloud Android Firestore Dependency failing related to io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.13.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-firestore, build.gradle

I'm getting this dependency error when trying to sync in Gradle with FireStore:

```
ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.13.1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.13.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core@[1.13.1], but grpc-core version was 1.16.1.
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to resolve the issue by implementing the requested version. Thanks for any help in advance.

Here is my app level build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.estebanrodriguez.anecdotals"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

//material design components
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'

//Android Architecture Components
def room_version = '2.0.0-beta01'

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

// Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

def lifecycle_version = '2.0.0-beta01'

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

//Timber
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

//Dagger 2
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-auth
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-auth', version: '1.13.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `grpc-core` version to 1.13.1?

Comment: `firebase-admin` [is for server-side application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486578/4815718) not Android app